# Counting how many times a value occurs inside an array grouped under another value (years)

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have an array with some information in it.

There are two important keys `datum` and `answer`.

This is my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 215
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 202
            [info_id] => 215
            [questionid] => 932
            [cid] => 202
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 215
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 202
            [info_id] => 215
            [questionid] => 930
            [cid] => 202
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 215
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 202
            [info_id] => 215
            [questionid] => 928
            [cid] => 202
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 215
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 202
            [info_id] => 215
            [questionid] => 926
            [cid] => 202
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 215
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 202
            [info_id] => 215
            [questionid] => 924
            [cid] => 202
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 215
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 202
            [info_id] => 215
            [questionid] => 922
            [cid] => 202
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 215
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 202
            [info_id] => 215
            [questionid] => 920
            [cid] => 202
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 215
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 202
            [info_id] => 215
            [questionid] => 918
            [cid] => 202
            [answer] => fout
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 215
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 202
            [info_id] => 215
            [questionid] => 916
            [cid] => 202
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 236
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2020
            [tid] => 324
            [catid] => 230
            [info_id] => 236
            [questionid] => 1192
            [cid] => 230
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 236
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2020
            [tid] => 324
            [catid] => 230
            [info_id] => 236
            [questionid] => 1191
            [cid] => 230
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 236
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2020
            [tid] => 324
            [catid] => 230
            [info_id] => 236
            [questionid] => 1190
            [cid] => 230
            [answer] => fout
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 236
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2020
            [tid] => 324
            [catid] => 230
            [info_id] => 236
            [questionid] => 1189
            [cid] => 230
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 235
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 329
            [catid] => 229
            [info_id] => 235
            [questionid] => 1187
            [cid] => 229
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 235
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 329
            [catid] => 228
            [info_id] => 235
            [questionid] => 1186
            [cid] => 228
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 235
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 329
            [catid] => 228
            [info_id] => 235
            [questionid] => 1185
            [cid] => 228
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 236
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2020
            [tid] => 324
            [catid] => 230
            [info_id] => 236
            [questionid] => 1188
            [cid] => 230
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 215
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 202
            [info_id] => 215
            [questionid] => 934
            [cid] => 202
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 215
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 202
            [info_id] => 215
            [questionid] => 936
            [cid] => 202
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 215
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 202
            [info_id] => 215
            [questionid] => 938
            [cid] => 202
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 215
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 202
            [info_id] => 215
            [questionid] => 940
            [cid] => 202
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 215
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 202
            [info_id] => 215
            [questionid] => 942
            [cid] => 202
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 215
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 202
            [info_id] => 215
            [questionid] => 944
            [cid] => 202
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 215
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 202
            [info_id] => 215
            [questionid] => 946
            [cid] => 202
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 215
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 202
            [info_id] => 215
            [questionid] => 948
            [cid] => 202
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 235
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 329
            [catid] => 228
            [info_id] => 235
            [questionid] => 1184
            [cid] => 228
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 230
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 220
            [info_id] => 230
            [questionid] => 1154
            [cid] => 220
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 230
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 220
            [info_id] => 230
            [questionid] => 1153
            [cid] => 220
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 230
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 220
            [info_id] => 230
            [questionid] => 1152
            [cid] => 220
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 230
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 220
            [info_id] => 230
            [questionid] => 1151
            [cid] => 220
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 230
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 220
            [info_id] => 230
            [questionid] => 1150
            [cid] => 220
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 230
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 220
            [info_id] => 230
            [questionid] => 1149
            [cid] => 220
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [32] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 230
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 220
            [info_id] => 230
            [questionid] => 1147
            [cid] => 220
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 230
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 220
            [info_id] => 230
            [questionid] => 1148
            [cid] => 220
            [answer] => fout
        )

    [34] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 230
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 220
            [info_id] => 230
            [questionid] => 1145
            [cid] => 220
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [35] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 230
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 220
            [info_id] => 230
            [questionid] => 1146
            [cid] => 220
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [36] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 230
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 220
            [info_id] => 230
            [questionid] => 1144
            [cid] => 220
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [37] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 230
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 220
            [info_id] => 230
            [questionid] => 1143
            [cid] => 220
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [38] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 230
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 220
            [info_id] => 230
            [questionid] => 1142
            [cid] => 220
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [39] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 230
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 220
            [info_id] => 230
            [questionid] => 1140
            [cid] => 220
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [40] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 230
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 220
            [info_id] => 230
            [questionid] => 1141
            [cid] => 220
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [41] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 230
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 220
            [info_id] => 230
            [questionid] => 1139
            [cid] => 220
            [answer] => ok
        )

    [42] => Array
        (
            [infoid] => 230
            [company_id] => 57
            [datum] => 2019
            [tid] => 327
            [catid] => 220
            [info_id] => 230
            [questionid] => 1138
            [cid] => 220
            [answer] => ok
        )

)
```

I would like to see how many times the key `answer` has the value `fout` grouped for each year (`datum` contains the year, so in this array there are two years 2019 and 2020)

How can I see how many times `fout` occurs for `datum` 2019 and 2020?

So for example I see this:

```
2019 - 5 times fout
2020 - 0 times fout
```

I tried counting inside my loop that creates my array, but for some reason it always returns 0.

This is what I tried before (a start):

```
while($getwpi = $getwpicon->fetch_assoc()){
  $year = date('Y', strtotime($getwpi['datum']));
  $getwpi['datum'] = $year; // update your field
  $wpi[] = $getwpi; // add to the result array
  $counted = count($wpi['datum']);
}
```

But `$counted` returns 0.

This is my loop at the moment:

```
while($getwpi = $getwpicon->fetch_assoc()){
  $year = date('Y', strtotime($getwpi['datum']));
  $getwpi['datum'] = $year; // update your field
  $wpi[] = $getwpi; // add to the result array
}
```

Comment: Count inside the loop that gathers this data to begin with, makes rather little sense. Either _count_ after the loop, or _add_ something to a counter variable inside the loop.

Comment: If your only goal is to get the count as you are asking for, then you could do this in SQL and not have to process the data after (same comment as on previous question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the count inside your loop:

```
while($getwpi = $getwpicon->fetch_assoc()){
  $year = date('Y', strtotime($getwpi['datum']));
  $getwpi['datum'] = $year; // update your field

  if ($getwpi['answer'] == "fout") {
      $res[$year] = isset($res[$year]) ? $res[$year] + 1 : 1;
  }
  $wpi[] = $getwpi; // add to the result array
}
```

Now the `$res` will be array with count for each year. You can loop on it and print what you need.

Comment: Thank you but this line is breaking my page: `$res[$year] = isset($res[$year]) ? isset($res[$year] + 1 : 1;` I get this error: `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ')' in /home/website/public_html/rapport.php on line 59`

Comment: @twan - my bad - forgot the extra `isset` - update the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_walk` and `array_key_exists` to approach this

```
$res=[];
array_walk($arr, function($v, $k) use (&$res){//$arr is the main array
  $res[$v['datum']] = (array_key_exists($v['datum'],$res) && !empty($v['answer'])) ? ($res[$v['datum']]+=1) : 1;
});
echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);
```

Output example:

```
Array
(
  [2019] => 4
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code  :) .

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
var theArray=Array({
            infoid: 1,
            company_id: 1,
            datum: 2019,
            tid: "aziz-elanzi",
            catid: "ELANZI",
            answer: "fout"
        },
  {
            infoid: 1,
            company_id: 1,
            datum: 2020,
            tid: "aziz-elanzi",
            catid: "ELANZI",
            answer: "fout"
        },
  {
            infoid: 1,
            company_id: 1,
            datum: 2019,
            tid: "aziz-elanzi",
            catid: "ELANZI",
            answer: "ok"
        },
  {
            infoid: 1,
            company_id: 1,
            datum: 2019,
            tid: "aziz-elanzi",
            catid: "ELANZI",
            answer: "fout"
        },
  {
            infoid: 1,
            company_id: 1,
            datum: 2019,
            tid: "aziz-elanzi",
            catid: "ELANZI",
            answer: "fout"
        },
  {
            infoid: 1,
            company_id: 1,
            datum: 2019,
            tid: "aziz-elanzi",
            catid: "ELANZI",
            answer: "fout"
        },
  {
            infoid: 1,
            company_id: 1,
            datum: 2020,
            tid: "aziz-elanzi",
            catid: "ELANZI",
            answer: "fout"
        });
 var count2019=0;
 var count2020=0;
   theArray.forEach(function(data) {
    if(data['answer']=='fout'){
   if (data['datum']==2019) count2019+=1;
   else if  (data['datum']==2020) count2020+=1;
    }
 }); 
 
alert('count2019 : '+count2019+' - count2020 : '+count2020);
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```